# Is it possible to find common xpath for this elements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, getattribute

xpath of one element is: `//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img[2]`

xpath of another element is: `//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img[1]`

Actually I need to check attribute of element must contains "red" after element gets **disabled**
after clicking "n" times, so I am using `element.getAttribute("src").contains("red");`
`element2.getAttribute("src").contains("red");`

Is it possible to find common xpath for this elements?

Comment: You mean: `//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img`? What are you asking?

Comment: That xpath of yours locates first element but fails for second.

Comment: Albeit `//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img` is the common xpath but how to use the xpath depends a lot on your usecase, what you want to do if either of the node is selected.

Comment: Will this work? `//div[@class='name-slider-header']//button//img[contains(@src,'red')][position()=1 or position()=2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following xpath to identify the `image` elements where `src` value contains `red`

```
//div[@class='name-slider-header']//button//img[contains(@src, 'red')]
```

code:

```
imgElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='name-slider-header']//button//img[contains(@src, 'red')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The common XPath of these 2 elements is `//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img`. So, you can get a list of elements and then iterate over the list extracting the element attribute, as following:

```java
elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=name-slider-header']//button//img"));
for(WebElement element : elements){
    if(element.getAttribute("src").contains("red")){
      // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cant we use **OR** in xpath like **|**?

Comment: we can use them. What did you intend to do? You need to check 2 elements, no?

Comment: I want common xpath which able to check 2 elements. elements xpath is same except that index path is varying.

Comment: You can not do that directly. `getAttribute()` can be applied on a single web element only, not on a list ob objects.